# Probability / Combinatorics basic question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a question I have not been able to solve.

There are three boxes.

Box 1 - three red, three white balls,

Box 2 - two red and three white balls

Box 3 - 4 red and 2 white balls.

A ball is picked at random from a randomly picked box, where the probabilities of choosing each box is 1:2:1.

a) What is the probability that a red ball is picked

b) Determine the ratio between the probability that a white ball is picked and the probability that a red ball is picked

c) If a red ball is picked, determine the probability that it was chosen from the second  box.

Comment: You can refer to “Law of Total Probability” and “Bayes Theorem” from  Wikipedia and then show your attempts first before asking for the solution

Comment: What did you try first? Maybe I can help you from their so that you can learn from it